# How to use awk to sum multiple columns (but not all) and sort by the summed values

Tags: sorting, awk

I hope that I can solve this problem with awk and/or sort:

I have an 19-column tab-delim file formatted like so: (Where the line beginning 'Gene' is my header)

```
Gene  -100 -75 -50 -25  0 25 50 75 100  -100 -75 -50 -25  0 25 50 75 100
MLL      0   0   0   2  5  2  0  0   1     0   0   4   8  5  5  4  0   1
MLL2     0   0   0   7 10  7  0  0   1     0   0   0   7 10  7  0  0   1
```

I would like to sum columns 2-10, and then sort the rows by this summed value, to give an output like so:

```
Gene  -100 -75 -50 -25  0 25 50 75 100  -100 -75 -50 -25  0 25 50 75 100
MLL2     0   0   0   7 10  7  0  0   1     0   0   0   7 10  7  0  0   1
MLL      0   0   0   2  5  2  0  0   1     0   0   4   8  5  5  4  0   1
```

I know that if I can make a 20th column with the sum value I need, then I can use sort to finish the job:

```
sort -nk20 file.txt
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Two step solution

This sums the columns and prints the sum as the 20th column:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $0,0;next;} {s=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; print $0,s;}' file
Gene  -100 -75 -50 -25  0 25 50 75 100  -100 -75 -50 -25  0 25 50 75 100 0
MLL      0   0   0   2  5  2  0  0   1     0   0   4   8  5  5  4  0   1 37
MLL2     0   0   0   7 10  7  0  0   1     0   0   0   7 10  7  0  0   1 50
```

The output of the above can now be piped, as you suggest, into `sort -nk20`.

#### One step solution

If you want to sum and sort in one step and if you have GNU awk, then use:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"} NR==1{print;next} {s=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; a[NR]=s; b[NR]=$0} END{for (i in a)print b[i]}' file
```

Or, written over multiple lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"} 
    NR==1{print;next} 
    {s=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; a[NR]=s; b[NR]=$0}
    END{for (i in a)print b[i]}' file
```

`PROCINFO` is a feature of GNU awk.

Comment: Thanks! That's almost exactly what I needed!

I needed to specify a certain range of columns (in this example 2-10, which I could do by substituting NF with 10.

I ended up using your two-step solution
    $ awk 'NR==1{print $0,0;next;} {s=0; for (i=2;i<=10;i++) s+=$i; print $0,s;}' file
, piping it into sort -r -nk20, which worked great.

Thanks again!